# How to integrate Dapper Wallet smart contracts with web app?

Tags: solidity, wallets, contract-invocation

Dapper Labs who are the creators of Cryptokitties recently released their own wallet which is run by smartcontracts. They have open sourced the code:

https://github.com/dapperlabs/dapper-contracts

I am looking for some guidance on how I could integrate their wallet (smart contracts) into a web app so that it's users each would have access to their own Dapper wallet.

Would it be possible to use web3.js and if so which provider would I ideally use?

Answer (score 1):

For authorization you can use [dappauth](https://github.com/dapperlabs/dappauth.js) from Dapper Labs.

I have been using it with Infura and works fine.